¿Por qué los números en mi gráfica aparecen sin ceros ni puntos?
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en PHP con Laravel y estoy generando gráficas de barras utilizando Chart.js. Estoy teniendo un problema con el formato de los números en la gráfica.
Tengo una función formatearNumero($numero) que formatea un número con ceros y puntos, utilizando sprintf("%08.3f", $numero). Luego, en mi controlador, estoy utilizando esta función para formatear los números que paso a mi vista.
function formatearNumero($numero)
{
    return sprintf("%08.3f", $numero);
}
public function graficas()
    {
        $prestamosAgrupados = Prestamo::selectRaw('MONTH(created_at) as mes, SUM(monto) as total_prestado')
            ->groupBy('mes')
            ->orderBy('mes')
            ->get();

        $meses = [];
        $totalesPrestados = [];
        $totalesPrestadosFormateados = [];

        foreach ($prestamosAgrupados as $prestamoAgrupado) {
            $meses[] = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $prestamoAgrupado->mes, 1));
            $totalesPrestados[] = $prestamoAgrupado->total_prestado;
            $totalesPrestadosFormateados[] = $this->formatearNumero($prestamoAgrupado->total_prestado);
        }

        $today = Carbon::today();
        $cuotasHoy = Cuota::whereDate('fecha', $today)->get();
        $sumaCuotasHoy = $cuotasHoy->sum('monto_cuota');

        return view('graficas', compact('sumaCuotasHoy', 'totalesPrestados', 'meses', 'totalesPrestadosFormateados'));
    }

En mi vista, estoy pasando los números formateados a mi gráfico de barras:
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('prestamoPorMesChart').getContext('2d');
var prestamoPorMesChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: @json($meses),
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Monto total prestado',
            data: @json($totalesPrestadosFormateados),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});

Asi se ve mi migracion
$table->decimal('monto', 8, 3);
En mi tabla prestamos el monto se guarda con punto tipo:
100.000
EDICION
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return value.toLocaleString('es-ES', {minimumFractionDigits: 0});
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});


eso debe tener que ver con la configuracion del sistema que lo manipula ... no me queda claro si ocurre en el frontend o backend, para ser el frontend ... ya que algunas libreria de javascript utilizan la configuracion regional del S.O.

@FranciscoNuñezIALover

Mira la parte editada

niidea de cual sea la parte editada ...

Ya la puse, la del fondo

pero esta usando el local de "es-ES" en  español de Españale los miles se separa por punto y los decimales por coma ... en ese pais ... cambialo por es-MX a ver que sucede pero eso si limpia el cache XD

Como seria para el caso de colombia

no se si tenga soporte para locales de colombia ... tendrias que investigarlo

aqui esta lo que soporta: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/locale.html

Ok gracias por la ayuda  voy a investigar mas

y tambien dice que se apega a este estandar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35.html#BCP_47_Conformance

site sirve me avisas para ponerlo de respuesta

Ok, intente de ponerlo como es-CO por que al parecer ese seria el soporte pero nada sigue mostrando igual yo creo que es tema al momento de formatear el numero

pero es que no has puestpo el formato del numero original (Raw) y de donde viene ... y por que en el camino aparece el punto ...

creo que este formato sprintf("%08.3f", $numero); tambien esta mal...

y esto creo que deberia de tener un dos: minimumFractionDigits: 2

Dejame intentar probar ese metodo y te comento

Debes agregar un [MCVE]. En tu caso, donde está la configuración de Chartjs debes agregar lo que renderiza PHP, es decir cambiar esto data: @json($totalesPrestadosFormateados), por lo que aparece en el navegador. Mismo caso con el label
